# Dynamically update D3 Sunburst if the source json is updated (item added or deleted)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I am new to D3 and trying to dynamically update the chart if the source json is modified. But I am not able to achieve this.

Please check [this plunkr](https://jsfiddle.net/opfp70qy/)

**Js:**

```
var width = 500,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

var y = d3.scale.sqrt()
    .range([0, radius]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + (height / 2 + 10) + ") rotate(-90 0 0)");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .value(function(d) {
        return d.size;
    });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) {
        return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x)));
    })
    .endAngle(function(d) {
        return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx)));
    })
    .innerRadius(function(d) {
        return Math.max(0, y(d.y));
    })
    .outerRadius(function(d) {
        return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy));
    });

//d3.json("/d/4063550/flare.json", function(error, root) {
var root = initItems;

var g = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(partition.nodes(root))
    .enter().append("g");

var path = g.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name);
    })
    .on("click", click)
    .each(function(d) {
        this.x0 = d.x;
        this.dx0 = d.dx;
    });


//.append("text")
var text = g.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return y(d.y);
    })
    .attr("dx", "6") // margin
    .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill", "white");

function computeTextRotation(d) {
    var angle = x(d.x + d.dx / 2) - Math.PI / 2;
    return angle / Math.PI * 180;
}



function click(d) {
    console.log(d)
    // fade out all text elements
    if (d.size !== undefined) {
        d.size += 100;
    };
    text.transition().attr("opacity", 0);

    path.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attrTween("d", arcTween(d))
        .each("end", function(e, i) {
            // check if the animated element's data e lies within the visible angle span given in d
            if (e.x >= d.x && e.x < (d.x + d.dx)) {
                // get a selection of the associated text element
                var arcText = d3.select(this.parentNode).select("text");
                // fade in the text element and recalculate positions
                arcText.transition().duration(750)
                    .attr("opacity", 1)
                    .attr("transform", function() {
                        return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(e) + ")"
                    })
                    .attr("x", function(d) {
                        return y(d.y);
                    });
            }
        });
} //});

// Word wrap!
var insertLinebreaks = function(t, d, width) {
    alert(0)
    var el = d3.select(t);
    var p = d3.select(t.parentNode);
    p.append("g")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
            return y(d.y);
        })
        //    .attr("dx", "6") // margin
        //.attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")";
        })
        //p
        .append("foreignObject")
        .attr('x', -width / 2)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", 200)
        .append("xhtml:p")
        .attr('style', 'word-wrap: break-word; text-align:center;')
        .html(d.name);
    alert(1)
    el.remove();
    alert(2)
};

//g.selectAll("text")
//    .each(function(d,i){ insertLinebreaks(this, d, 50 ); });


d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

// Interpolate the scales!
function arcTween(d) {
    var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
        yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
        yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
    return function(d, i) {
        return i ? function(t) {
            return arc(d);
        } : function(t) {
            x.domain(xd(t));
            y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t));
            return arc(d);
        };
    };
}

function arcTweenUpdate(a) {
    console.log(path);
    var _self = this;
    var i = d3.interpolate({ x: this.x0, dx: this.dx0 }, a);
    return function(t) {
        var b = i(t);
        console.log(window);
        _self.x0 = b.x;
        _self.dx0 = b.dx;
        return arc(b);
    };
}

setTimeout(function() {
    path.data(partition.nodes(newItems))
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attrTween("d", arcTweenUpdate)

}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to what @Cyril has suggested about removing the following line:

```
d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");
```

I made further modifications in your fiddle: [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rogunt4h/1/)

The idea used here is to add a function `updateChart` which takes the `items` and then generate the chart:

```
var updateChart = function (items) {
    // code to update the chart with new items
}

updateChart(initItems);

setTimeout(function () { updateChart(newItems); }, 2000);
```

This doesn't use the `arcTweenUpdate` function you have created but I will try to explain the underlying concept:

First, you will need to `JOIN` the new data with your existing data:

```
// DATA JOIN - Join new data with old elements, if any.
var gs = svg.selectAll("g").data(partition.nodes(root));
```

then, `ENTER` to create new elements if required:

```
// ENTER
var g = gs.enter().append("g").on("click", click);
```

But, we also need to `UPDATE` the existing/new `path` and `text` nodes with new data:

```
// UPDATE
var path = g.append("path");

 gs.select('path')
  .style("fill", function(d) {
      return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name);
  })
  //.on("click", click)
  .each(function(d) {
      this.x0 = d.x;
      this.dx0 = d.dx;
  })
  .transition().duration(500)
  .attr("d", arc);


  var text = g.append("text");

  gs.select('text')
  .attr("x", function(d) {
      return y(d.y);
  })
  .attr("dx", "6") // margin
  .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")";
  })
  .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
  })
  .style("fill", "white");
```

and, after everything is created/updated remove the `g` nodes which are not being used i.e. `EXIT`:

```
// EXIT - Remove old elements as needed.
gs.exit().transition().duration(500).style("fill-opacity", 1e-6).remove();
```

This whole pattern of `JOIN + ENTER + UPDATE + EXIT` is demonstrated in following articles by Mike Bostock:

1. [General Update Pattern - I](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218)
2. [General Update Pattern - II](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808221)
3. [General Update Pattern - III](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234)

Comment: Great Answer. How can we provide the tool tip (Name and Value) for each section of the graph?

Answer (score 2):

In side the fiddle the `setTimeout` is not running because:

```
d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");
```

You will get *Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'frame' property from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin "https://fiddle.jshell.net" from accessing a frame with origin* and the setTimeout never gets called.

So you can remove this line     `d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");` just for the fiddle.

Apart from that:

Your timeout function should look like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    //remove the old graph 
  svg.selectAll("*").remove();
  root = newItems;
  g = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(partition.nodes(newItems))
    .enter().append("g");
  /make path
  path = g.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name);
    })
    .on("click", click)
    .each(function(d) {
      this.x0 = d.x;
      this.dx0 = d.dx;
    });
  //make text
  text = g.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return y(d.y);
    })
    .attr("dx", "6") // margin
    .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill", "white");

}
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/b39sny10/)

Comment: I need solution where I am not removing the whole graph completely and redrawing the whole graph again instead it should be something similar to what happens on click where we update the graph with Twean animation.

Answer (score 1):

for the enter() and transitions to work you need to give d3 a way to identify each item in your data. the .data() function has a second parameter that lets you return something to use as an id. enter() will use the id to decide whether the object is new.

try changing

```
path.data(partition.nodes(newItems))
.data(partition.nodes(root));
```

to

```
path.data(partition.nodes(newItems), function(d){return d.name});
.data(partition.nodes(root), function(d){return d.name});
```